# Array of Tuples-IBM Cplex

Tags: cplex

I have defined an array called `A` in IBM CPlex indexed over a set.

The set is a set of edges in a graph such as `{<1,2>,<1,3>,...}`. Each edge is defined as a tuple.

In the post-processing part, I put `writeln(A[<1,2>])` but I have got no idea why I can not get the amount of the related array element and I will face a strange error.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code to print out the value of the array element. It may fit your situation. Note that `matchup2` is an array of tuples.

```cpp
execute PostProcess
{
    var m=0;
    
    for (var w=1; w<=nbWeeks; w++)
    {
        for (var d=1; d<=nbDaysPerWeek; d++)
            for (var s=1; s<=nbSlotsPerDay; s++)
            {
                write("W"+w+" D"+d+" S"+s+" ");
                for (var c=1; c<=nbLocations; c++)
                {
                    ++m;
                    write("<"+matchup2[mList[m]].a+","+matchup2[mList[m]].b+"> ");
                }
                writeln();
            }
        writeln();
    }           
}
```